# Bandpass FIR filter labview

Tags: filter, labview, bandpass-filter

I am trying to make a bandpass FIR filter in Labview. I have created two sine waves (one with freq = 1Hz, amplitude = 1 and the second with freq=50, amplitude = 0.1) that I added together. 
[image: Input signal]

And now I want to create a bandpass filter to filter out the 50Hz signal (I know that its possible use just low pass filter, but I need to use bandpass filter). I set the low cutoff freq to 0.01 and high cutoff freq to 3, but the result is witout any change.

[image]On top of that when I change the parameters I get no change.

When I use the butterworth filter I get the result that I am looking for. [image]

This is my code:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give us a [snippet](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/)?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you just need to play with the settings to find the ones that suite you the most.

See the example bellow:
[image]

And its [snippet](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/) (drag and drop the image into a blank VI):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You say you need to use a Bandpass filter, but in your VI you are using a Bandstop filter. Not sure which of the two is the error. Just as a recap:

- Lowpass filter passes anything below the set freq.
- Highpass filter passes anything above the set freq.
- Bandpass filter passes anything between the set freq.
- Bandstop filter passes everything except the part between the set
  freq.

The Butterworth part has nothing to do with high, low  or bandpass but with how fast the fall-off is after the set frequency.

See the image for a working vi and results.
[image: VI Snippet]
[image: Graph]

Hope this helps.